# Batch Script Loop That Skips Matched Values

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an existing script that loops through a list of folders, and deletes a file from each folder found. I want the script to skip specific folders in the list based on name.

Here is the existing script:

```
for /d %%F in (c:\users\*) do del "%%F\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms" /s /q
```

In this case, I would want it to skip the "admin" folder found "c:\users".

Comment: You could go as simple as, `Do If /I Not "%%~nxF" == "admin" Del …`

Answer (score 0):

The code below is designed for Windows 10, as your task is for resetting the Quick Access Pinned Folders in its File Explorer.

The code already ignores the 'Special' PC accounts, that includes, but may not be limited to, `Administrator`, `DefaultAccount`, `Guest`, and `WDAGUtilityAccountdefault`.

If you have other named accounts you want to exclude from this task, you could insert them at line 7 between `'` and `"` using the following syntax:  `And Name='firstName' Or Name='anotherName' Or Name='additionalName'`

For example:

> `"LocalAccount='TRUE' And Name='admin' Or Name='john' Or Name='jane'"`

Nothing else should be modified, added or removed for testing purposes.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "SubPath=AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations"
Set "FileName=f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms"
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where
 "LocalAccount='TRUE'"
 Get SID /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where
 "SID='%%G' And Special!='TRUE' And LocalPath Is Not Null" Get LocalPath
 /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do Del /A /F "%%H\%SubPath%\%FileName%" 2>NUL
```

The code may look complex, but its benefits are that it ignores 'Special' accounts, and it does not limit their local profile paths to `C:\Users`. Not every user has to have their profile directory in the default location, so this determines that location without making such assumptions.

I have also modified your `Del` command options because the file you are wanting to delete is not located one or more times within the tree, negating `/S`, and as you are not using a global wildcard, you do not need the `/Q` option either. I have included the `/A` and `/F` options just in case the file has problematic attributes, just to improve the chances of successful deletion.

Please be aware that if your task involves removing files from another user's profile tree, then the invoker of the task must have the required permissions to do so.